# How to initiate objects from different classes in a loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to initiate objects from different classes and the args are in a list. The type of class needs to be set by the args in the list and I want to avoid conditional statements that it could be scalable for more classes.
The initiated object will be added to a list of objects.

for example:

```
example_list = [['x', 20], ['p', 50], ['d', 100]

obj_list = []

for i in example_list:
    if i[0] == 'x':
        xylophone = Xylophone('x', 20)
        obj_list.append(xylophone)
    if i[0] == 'p':
        piano = Piano('p', 50)
        obj_list.append(piano)
    if i[0] == 'd':
        drum = Drum('d', 100)
        obj_list.append(drum)
```

Comment: Point in a direction: Try using a dictionary as a switch case.

Comment: You should use a dictionnary

Comment: If all of the classes have the same interface, as it looks like they do, you could have a dictionary mapping letter to class: `instruments = {"x": Xylophone, ...}` then instantiate them in a list comprehension: `obj_list = [instruments[letter](letter, number) for letter, number in example_list]`. It does seem odd that the letter is used both to determine which class should be instantiated *and* passed as an argument, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah...or maybe something like: `[instruments[letter](letter, *args) for letter, *args in example_list]`... (then it's fairly straight-forward to drop the `letter` argument if it's not really required...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *classes are objects* in python, you could do

```
classes = dict(
    x=Xylophone,
    p=Piano,...)

for class_name, arg in my_list:
    cls = classes[class_name]
    object = cls(class_name, arg)
```